# Network card names (eth0, eth1) missing after replacing the motherboard

Tags: networking, debian

I installed a new Mainboard (and CPU and RAM) (ASRock H97 Pro4, with Intel Gigabit Ethernet on-board), and am trying to get my existing LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition) to work with it. So far so good, but no internet.

The internet is managed with commandline, using `pon dsl-provider`. This now shows

```
Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
/usr/sbin/pppd: In file /etc/ppp/peers/dsl-provider: unrecognized option 'eth1'
```

`sudo pppoeconf` shows "Sorry, no working ethernet card could be found."

`/sbin/ifconfig` shows there is no eth0 or eth1 whatsoever. The only entry there is the `lo` (Loopback).

There are some other articles that suggest that eth0 or eth1 might just have been renamed to something else, e.g. to `enp0s10`. But then the renamed thing would show up in ifconfig, which it does not.

I also tried `sudo service networking stop` (works) and `sudo service networking start`. The second command gives:

```
[....] Configuring network interfaces...eth1: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Failed to bring up dsl-provider.
done.
```

And still only `lo` in ifconfig.

`ip addr show eth0` (and with eth1 likewise) shows:

```
dig: couldn't get address for 'resolver1.opendns.com': not found
```

`lspci -v` shows:

```
[..]

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 15a1
        Flags bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
        Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at f7238000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
        Capabilities: <access denied>

[..]
```

---

EDIT I:
Funny, I thought I already wrote something about the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file. Maybe I deleted it while writing the post.

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x100e (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:52:fe:13", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:04:00.0 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1f:d0:91:e1:68", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# PCI device 0x1814:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:05:01.0 (rt61pci)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:21:29:66:32:7a", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# USB device 0x:0x (r8712u)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:14:5c:8b:db:40", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```

I suppose the two lines related to ethernet are both from the old board. So if I remove them, nothing is left.

Also, the file says it will be regenerated with `/lib/udev/write_net_rules`. According to other articles on the web, this can happen either manually or automatically on reboot if the file is removed/renamed/missing. In my case, however, nothing is regenerated on reboot. Running `/lib/udev/write_net_rules` manually first shows "missing $INTERFACE". When following [these instructions](http://kmadac.github.io/posts/18-Regenerate-net-udev-rules-in-ubuntu-12.04/), the `ip addr show $INTERFACE` is where it fails. This is why I posted `ip addr show eth0` above. Doing it in a different way (don't remember) showed that the output file is locked (and I don't think it was about file write permissions).

---

EDIT II:
I installed an additional PCI ethernet card to see if this works. At first this added a line in lspci, but nothing new in ifconfig. Now after more reboots and installing an additional HD (side effect?), I get an `eth2` in ifconfig. I don't know if this is the PCI card or the onboard card.

`sudo pppoeconf` does pick up the eth2, but then fails to configure an internet connection with it, saying "the Access Concentrator of your provider did not respond."

Anyway, I should probably try to rename it back to eth0 / eth1 instead of eth2. Working on it.

Comment: Have you tried booting any other distros from a live CD (or USB)? If the ethernet is working in another Linux distro you could try to replicate the setup or install that other distro.

Comment: @KasperSouren: This is something to try next. Unfortunately my DVD is not working since the new board. It is connected and somewhat half-recognized, but no boot DVD works, and Linux can't read any DVD either. Different problem / can of worms, I guess, not to be discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a guess, but — I hope — right on the point.

### Some background

These days device naming and creating entries in the `/dev` filesystem is managed by the `udev` daemon, which is necessarily installed in stock Debians.  To make network card interface names predictable, `udev` binds them to their MAC addresses (low-level hardware address, which, for Ethernet cards, is only seen on the Ethernet layer).  When `udev` observes a network interface appear *for the first time,* it generates an `etnN` name for it, and updates a file with network interface naming rules which, in Debian, is

```
% ls -1 /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

> On a side note, I beleive it's not really `udev` itself which updates this file, but rather some script provided by Debian `udev` calls when it sees a network interface card's device appearing, but the exact mechanics are not relevant to our case.

The problem with your replacing the motherboard is that the new card has a MAC address different to that of the card on the old motherboard, and so the interface created for this new card has a name different to those already in the "rules" file.

### How to fix

I would just open that rules file with any text editor, deleted all the lines pertaining to the cards from the old motherboard, and edited the only left one to read `eth0` for the interface name.

After saving the file you can run

```
# udevadm trigger
```

to see your network card reappear under the name `eth0`.
(If that does not help, run `service udev restart` or reboot as a last resort.)

---

A side note: `ip addr ...` is not really useful in your case because it deals with IP-level, and you're struggling with configuring a link level — a lower one.  So you'd try the `ip link` command to list available networking "links" which generally mean network access cards.

Comment: The two lines with eth(something) are for eth0 and eth1. I suppose both are from the old board. So if I remove these two lines, then nothing eth-related will be left. (The other two lines are for wlan0 and wlan1). I can't easily copy-paste the lines cause I'm on a different machine..

Comment: If the above doesn't work, look carefully in /var/log/dmesg or at the boot text of your system.  Your NIC may be recognized but a non-free firmware file may be needed for it to actually show up and function.  May be the case if it's certain types of Intel cards or others (like `tg3`).

Comment: Question updated. @ultrasawblade: What would I look for in /var/log/dmesg?

Comment: @donquixote, do `dmesg | grep -i eth` to see anything the kernel printed about ethernet devices it had been able to activate.  It might turn out the built-in network card is not supported by available drivers (unlikely but still a possibility).

Comment: try something like `grep firmware /var/log/dmesg` or `grep firmware /var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: All I get here (with both commands) is entries of the type "platform microcode: firmware: agent loaded intel-ucode/06-3c-03 into memory"

Comment: @kostix: I see a number of entries with `dmesg | grep -i eth`, but I think they are mostly related to the added Realtek PCI card. Maybe I need to remove that again to continue this troubleshooting session in a way that is useful for others. But before that I will try to get the rest of the system to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did that (kind of) solved the problem for me. I would not say this is a universal solution. Especially because not everyone has a spare PCI ethernet card.

1. Install a PCI ethernet card (in addition to the on-board card). In my case this is an old Realtek RTL-8139.
2. Rename the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.
3. (possibly do some unrelated things, like connect a new HD, or dance around the fire)
4. Reboot.
5. Run `sudo pppoeconf`. If it asks you to do a backup, do it. Then follow the steps.

Result (for me):

- ifconfig shows the added PCI ethernet card as eth0, but no further eth* entries beyond that (only `lo` and `ppp0`).
- File `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` has NOT been regenerated. It is absent, nonexisting.
- Internet works.

I suppose this means that the on-board ethernet still has not been recognized. I assume that the new on-board ethernet is somewhat technically superior to the old PCI card. But I don't know how much of a practical difference this makes.